# How to normalize set of images between (-1,1)

Tags: python, matlab, tensorflow, pytorch

i have a dataset on images and i would like to normalize them betwwen (-1,1) before feeding them to NN how can i do that ?

```
x=sample
#Normalized Data
normalized = (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))

# Histogram of example data and normalized data
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(x,          breaks=10, xlab="Data",            col="lightblue", main="")
hist(normalized, breaks=10, xlab="Normalized Data", col="lightblue", main="")
```

i found this code online but it did not solve my problem since  i have image dataset

Comment: ``normalized = (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))``, just extend this formula to a 2D array (= an 'image').
If you still want a precise answer, you should tell us how your images are imported into python (numpy ? cv2 ?) and in what format.

Comment: imported as numpy in png format

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your image `img_array` is an `np.array` :

```
normalized_input = (img_array - np.amin(img_array)) / (np.amax(img_array) - np.amin(img_array))
```

Will normalize your data between 0 and 1.

Then, `2*normalized_input-1` will shift it between -1 and 1

If you want to normalize multiple images, you can make it a function :

```
def normalize_negative_one(img):
    normalized_input = (img - np.amin(img)) / (np.amax(img) - np.amin(img))
    return 2*normalized_input - 1
```

Then iterate over a e.g. list, tuple of images called `imgs` :

```
for i,img in enumerate(imgs):
    imgs[i] = normalize_negative_one(img)
```

Comment: thank you  let us say i am using pytorhc , should i put this line inside the __getitem__?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that, should it belong to the same question ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `img` is the name of your image

```
import numpy as np
normalized = 2*[(img - img.min()) / (img.max() - img.min())] - 1
```

Should give you the normalized image between -1 an 1

Comment: but this is just for one image , i want to normalize a dataset of 30 images